# Multiselect listview with background change not working for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control to perform multiselect on a listview.

Viewcell code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ____
{
    public class SelectMultipleBasePage<T> : ContentPage
    {
        public class WrappedSelection<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public T Item { get; set; }
            bool isSelected = false;
            public bool IsSelected
            {
                get
                {
                    return isSelected;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (isSelected != value)
                    {
                        isSelected = value;
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                        //                      PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (nameof (IsSelected))); // C# 6
                    }
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        }
        public class BackGroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    if ((bool)value)
                    {
                        return Color.FromRgb(214, 221, 228);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Color.White;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Color.White;
                }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

        }

        public class WrappedItemSelectionTemplate : ViewCell
        {
            public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate()
                : base()
            {
                Grid objGrid = new Grid();
                objGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
                {
                    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                });
                //
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(75, GridUnitType.Absolute),
                });
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                });
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = GridLength.Auto
                });

                //
                // Column 1:-
                Image objImage = new Image();
                objImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Item.Image"));
                objGrid.Children.Add(objImage, 0, 0);
                objGrid.Padding = new Thickness(10);
                //
                // Column 2:-
                StackLayout objStackLayoutCol2 = new StackLayout();
                objGrid.Children.Add(objStackLayoutCol2, 1, 0);

                Label name = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Name",
                    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["LabelStyle"] ,
                };
                Label date = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Date",
                    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["LabelStyleTiny"] 
                };
                name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Name"));
                date.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Date"));
                objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(name);
                objStackLayoutCol2.Padding = new Thickness(10,10,10,10);
                objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(date);

                objGrid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundColorProperty, "IsSelected", converter: new BackGroundColorConverter());

                //
                var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = "More" };
                moreAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
                moreAction.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                };

                var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background
                deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
                deleteAction.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                };

                ContextActions.Add(moreAction);
                ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);

                View = objGrid;


            }
        }
        public List<WrappedSelection<T>> WrappedItems = new List<WrappedSelection<T>>();
        public SelectMultipleBasePage(List<T> items)
        {
            WrappedItems = items.Select(item => new WrappedSelection<T>() { Item = item, IsSelected = false }).ToList();
            ListView mainList = new ListView()
            {
                ItemsSource = WrappedItems,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WrappedItemSelectionTemplate)),
            };

            mainList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                var o = (WrappedSelection<T>)e.SelectedItem;
                o.IsSelected = !o.IsSelected;
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //de-select
            };
            Content = mainList;

            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            {   // fix issue where rows are badly sized (as tall as the screen) on WinPhone8.1
                mainList.RowHeight = 40;
                // also need icons for Windows app bar (other platforms can just use text)
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("All", "check.png", SelectAll, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("None", "cancel.png", SelectNone, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
            }
            else
            {
                mainList.RowHeight = 60;
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("All", null, SelectAll, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("None", null, SelectNone, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
            }
        }
        void SelectAll()
        {
            foreach (var wi in WrappedItems)
            {
                wi.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
        void SelectNone()
        {
            foreach (var wi in WrappedItems)
            {
                wi.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
        public List<T> GetSelection()
        {
            return WrappedItems.Where(item => item.IsSelected).Select(wrappedItem => wrappedItem.Item).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

this code works perfectly for android. It selects multiple rows as per my requirement, but same code does not work for iOS. On iOS the background change does not work as expected. It sometimes select rows on single tap and sometimes on double tap. Not sure what is wrong.

Can anybody help me resolve the issue? Or could suggest any other way to achieve **multi-select feature**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding a tick feature.

Here is how I did it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ----
{
    public class SelectMultipleBasePage<T> : ContentPage
    {
        public delegate void ImageSelectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public event ImageSelectedHandler OnImageSelected;

        public class WrappedSelection<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public T Item { get; set; }
            bool isSelected = false;
            public bool IsSelected
            {
                get
                {
                    return isSelected;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (isSelected != value)
                    {
                        isSelected = value;
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                        //                      PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (nameof (IsSelected))); // C# 6
                    }
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        }
        public class TickConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    if ((bool)value)
                    {
                        return Device.OnPlatform("Images/checked_checkbox.png", "checked_checkbox.png", "Images/checked_checkbox.png");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Device.OnPlatform("Images/unchecked_checkbox.png", "unchecked_checkbox.png", "Images/unchecked_checkbox.png");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Device.OnPlatform("Images/unchecked_checkbox.png", "unchecked_checkbox.png", "Images/unchecked_checkbox.png");

                }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

        }

        public class WrappedItemSelectionTemplate : ViewCell
        {
            private readonly ImageSelectedHandler _parentHandler;

            static int i = 0; 
            public WrappedItemSelectionTemplate(ImageSelectedHandler parentHandler)
                : base()
            {

                _parentHandler = parentHandler;
                List<ListItems> items = new List<ListItems>();
                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("SelectedPage"))
                {
                    if (Application.Current.Properties["SelectedPage"].ToString() == "recording")
                    {
                        items = RecordingListPage.items;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items = RecordingDetailsPage.items;
                    }
                }

                Grid objGrid = new Grid();
                //
                objGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
                {
                    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                });
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(75, GridUnitType.Absolute),
                });
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
                });
                objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(75, GridUnitType.Absolute),
                });

                // Column 1:-
                Image objImage = new Image();
                objImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Item.Image"));
                objGrid.Children.Add(objImage, 0, 0);
                StackLayout objStackLayoutCol2 = new StackLayout();
                objGrid.Children.Add(objStackLayoutCol2, 1, 0);

                Label name = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Name",
                    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["LabelStyle"],
                };
                Label date = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Date",
                    Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["LabelStyleTiny"]
                };
                name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Name"));
                date.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Item.Date"));
                objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(name);
                objStackLayoutCol2.Children.Add(date);
                objStackLayoutCol2.Padding = new Thickness(10);

                Image objImageView = new Image();
                objImageView.Source = Device.OnPlatform("Icons/ic_mode_edit.png", "Search.png", "Images/Search.png");//ImageSource.FromFile("Search.png");

                StackLayout stv = new StackLayout();
                stv.Children.Add(objImageView);
                stv.Padding = new Thickness(10);
                stv.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                stv.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

                objImageView.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "IsSelected", converter: new TickConverter());


                objImage.StyleId = items[i].Id.ToString();
                i++;
                if (i == items.Count)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }

                var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += OnImageBtnTapped;
                objImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

                objGrid.Children.Add(stv, 2, 0);
                var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = "More" };

                moreAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
                moreAction.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                };

                var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background
                deleteAction.Icon = Device.OnPlatform("Icons/cancel.png", "cancel.png", "Images/cancel.png");
                deleteAction.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
                deleteAction.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                };

                //
                // add context actions to the cell
                //
                ContextActions.Add(moreAction);
                ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);

                StackLayout st = new StackLayout();
                st.Children.Add(objGrid);
                st.Children.Add(new BoxView() { Color = Color.FromHex("#A4B3C1"), WidthRequest = 100, HeightRequest = 1 });


                View = st;


            }
            private void OnImageBtnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //...
                _parentHandler.Invoke(sender, e);
            }
        }
        public static List<WrappedSelection<T>> WrappedItems = new List<WrappedSelection<T>>();
        public SelectMultipleBasePage(List<T> items)
        {
            WrappedItems = items.Select(item => new WrappedSelection<T>() { Item = item, IsSelected = false }).ToList();
            ListView mainList = new ListView()
            {
                ItemsSource = WrappedItems,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new WrappedItemSelectionTemplate(HandleImageSelected)),

            };

            mainList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                var o = (WrappedSelection<T>)e.SelectedItem;
                o.IsSelected = !o.IsSelected;
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //de-select
            };
            Content = mainList;
            mainList.HasUnevenRows = true;


            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            {   
                mainList.RowHeight = 40;
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("All", "check.png", SelectAll, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("None", "cancel.png", SelectNone, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
            }
            else
            {
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("All", null, SelectAll, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
                ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("None", null, SelectNone, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
            }
        }

        private void HandleImageSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnImageSelected != null)
            {
                OnImageSelected(sender, e);
            }
        }
        void SelectAll()
        {
            foreach (var wi in WrappedItems)
            {
                wi.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
        void SelectNone()
        {
            foreach (var wi in WrappedItems)
            {
                wi.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
        public static List<T> GetSelection()
        {
            return WrappedItems.Where(item => item.IsSelected).Select(wrappedItem => wrappedItem.Item).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I removed `BackgroundColorProperty` of the grid and have added new column with image of which source property is set based on the row selected.

Hope this helps anyone facing similar issue.